# Increment not working in matching game

Tags: javascript

I am trying to call the same function with incremented **numberOfFaces**, but it loading with previous value of 5 only. What am I doing wrong? All I am trying to do is repeat the function after I click on the last child of the leftside.

```
var numberOfFaces = 5;

    function generateFaces() {


        var theRightSide = document.getElementById("rightSide");
        var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");

        var theBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

        while(numberOfFaces > 0) {
            // CREATING IMG ELEMENTS AND APPENDING THEM TO THE LEFTSIDE DIV
            var img = document.createElement("img");
            img.src = "http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png" ;
            img.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400) +"px";
            img.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400) +"px";
            theLeftSide.appendChild(img);

            // CLONING THE LEFT SIDE DIV ELEMENTS, REMOVING THE LAST CHILD AND APPENDING THEM TO THE RIGHT CHILD
            var leftSideImages = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);
            leftSideImages.removeChild(leftSideImages.lastChild);
            theRightSide.appendChild(leftSideImages);
            numberOfFaces--;
        }

        theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick = function nextLevel(event){
            event.stopPropagation();
            while (theLeftSide.firstChild) {
                theLeftSide.removeChild(theLeftSide.firstChild);
            }
            while (theRightSide.firstChild) {
                theRightSide.removeChild(theRightSide.firstChild);
            }   
            numberOfFaces += 5;
            generateFaces(); 
        };

        theBody.onclick = function gameOver(event) {
            alert("Game Over!");
            theBody.onclick = null;
            theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick = null;
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Where You are checking/using numberOfFaces?

Comment: post the rest of your code....

Comment: There's no way to know based on the code you've shown. Possible reasons include re-running the code that initializes the variable, or the variable is local, or the code that prints the value is faulty, or any other reason.

Comment: I shared the full code now..check please!

Comment: Well ok, based on the full code `generateFaces()` runs the loop again that resets the variables value back to zero.

Comment: `nextLevel`  calls `generateFaces` which has `while(numberOfFaces > 0) { ... numberOfFaces--;}`

Comment: so what should I do then?

Comment: Why do you reset the variable back to zero if you don't want it to get reset to zero? Just use a normal for loop.

Comment: used this "for(var i = 0; i < numberOfFaces.length; i++) {"
still not solved! now its not even showing the images at all.

Comment: `numberOfFaces` is a number. It doesn't have a `length` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
        numberOfFaces += 5;
        generateFaces();
```

Your `numberOfFaces` value is `5` and you add `5` to it, so the result is `10`. After that you call generateFaces, which will decrement numberOfFaces until it reaches `0`, generating `10` faces and at next call will generate `5` faces according to the expectation. This happens inside `theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick`, so you expect your code to generate the faces and have `numberOfFaces` as `0` at the end when you click on that element. However, this `click` handler is defined inside `generateFaces`, which is never called, hence `numberOfFaces` is never changed. You need to refactor your code. Define your event handlers outside `generateFaces` and you should be ok after that.